# Mysql select next month from a month string column

Tags: mysql

How can I select records from next month if I have a column called "month" that contains string representations of the actual month names?

```
SELECT * FROM minutes WHERE year = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND month =
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, never mind:

```
SELECT * FROM  minutes WHERE year = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND month = MONTHNAME(now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```